# Ruby: How to get the indices of the first x array elements that match a condition?

Tags: ruby

I have two huge arrays of sentences, one in German and one in English. I will search through the German sentences for sentences that contain a certain word and if they do, I will check if there is an equivalent English sentence (using a hash with connection information). However, if the user is looking for a very common word, I don't want to return every single sentence that contains it but only the first x matches and stop searching then.

If I do `german_sentences.index { |sentence| sentence.include?(word) }` I get only one match at a time. 
If I use `german_sentences.keep_if { |sentence| sentence.include?(word) }` I get all matches, but also lose the index information, which is really critical for this.

I am now using a custom loop with each_with_index and break once the maximum has been reached, but I really feel that I must be missing some existing solution, at least something that gives a limited number of matches (even if not their indices)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
german_sentences
.each_index
.lazy
.select{|i| german_sentences[i].include?(word)}
.first(n)
```

Comment: A great reason to use Ruby 2.0 rather than 1.9.3 :-D

Comment: sawa, I'd be grateful if you could explain something for me.  When I run your code in irb (after initializing `german_sentences`, `word` and `n`), I get a syntax error (`unexpected '.'`) for each line continuation.  I know Ruby has smarts in recognizing a line continuation when `\` is not present, and I'm sure that when you run your code it works fine.  Could that be because you have included some (Rails?) code that permits line breaks as you have them?

Comment: @Cary, chances are you are running an earlier version of Ruby than is sawa.  Try 1.9.3, and if that doesn't work, 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, @Wayne.  I'm running 2.0.  I've since noticed that the problem only occurred in IRB and PRY, where it could not be expected to work.

Answer (score 1):

If your need is not a one-off, you could use [Module#refine](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-refine), rather than monkeypatching `Array`). `refine` was added to v2.0 experimentally, then changed considerably in v. 2.1.  One of the restrictions in the use of refine is: ["You may only activate refinements at top-level..."](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), which evidently prevents testing in Pry and IRB.

```
module M
  refine Array do
    def select_indices_first(n)
      i = 0
      k = 0
      a = []
      return a if n == 0
      each { |x| (a << i; k += 1) if yield(x); break if k == n; i += 1 }
      a
    end

    def select_first(n) # if you wanted this also...
      k = 0
      a = []
      return a if n == 0
      each { |x| (a << x; k += 1) if yield(x); break if k == n }
      a
    end
  end
end

using M

sentences = ["How now brown", "Cat", "How to guide", "How to shop"]
sentences.select_indices_first(0)  {|s| s.include?("How")} # => []
sentences.select_indices_first(1)  {|s| s.include?("How")} # => [0]
sentences.select_indices_first(2)  {|s| s.include?("How")} # => [0, 2]
sentences.select_indices_first(3)  {|s| s.include?("How")} # => [0, 2, 3]
sentences.select_indices_first(99) {|s| s.include?("How")} # => [0, 2, 3]

sentences.select_first(2) {|s| s.include?("How")} 
  # => ["How now brown", "How to guide"]
```